# How to test links with RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a side navigation menu and top navigation menu rendering using partials on all pages. On the welcome page, I am trying to check the clicks. I have this, but it is not working at the moment.

```
it "Checks the home link"
  get '/welcome'
  sleep 5
  page.should have_content("Basis tool")
end
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I am trying to check the clicks."?

Comment: Trying to click the link_to's

Answer (score 0):

If something is not getting selected as you expected, try using one of the alternative [selectors from the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RSpecMatchers#have_css-instance_method). There are also helpful [cheatsheets](https://gist.github.com/them0nk/2166525) that show usage.